# Ajp invalid message received with signature

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, mod-proxy, proxypass

I am using Tomcat 7.0.29 fronted with Apache 2.2.22 modproxy. 
Configured Ajp as the protocol in httpd.conf and AjpNioProtocol in server.xml. 
After the server starts, the logs are filled with the following message:

> Severe: Invalid message received with signature 20599
>   com.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader

There are no requests sent to the web or tomcat server and it still throws that error. Access logs in tomcat and apache show that no request is coming in. 
What is causing the invalid message error?

Here is the configuration :

- httpd.conf

  ```
  ProxyPass /wl ajp:// ip : port /wl
  ProxyPassReverse /wl ajp:// ip : port /wl
  ```
- server.xml

  ```
  <Connector port="port" 
             protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol" 
             connectionTimeout="20000" 
             acceptorThreadCount="2" 
             maxThreads="1600" 
             redirectPort="8443" />
  ```

Comment: Here is the server.xml --> <Connector port="port" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol" connectionTimeout="20000" acceptorThreadCount="2" maxThreads="600" redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: Can you provide your current configuration to avoid this ?
what is to be added and what is to be removed from which file

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For me, the problem was simple. I was sending HTTP requests but the connector was configured with AJP protocol. My connector in `server.xml` was configured like this:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

But when I changed it to this:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

The error went away.

Hopefully that will help someone with this error.

Comment: By default there's a HTTP-connector configured on some other port like 8080. So instead of using the AJP-port, one should reconfigure the calling application to not use 8009 with HTTP, but the other port, e.g. 8080 instead. That follows the standard conventions better.

Answer (score 11):

This may also happen when buffer sizes are not same at both ends: logs mention invalid AJP message and browser receive `400` error code.

I have fixed the situation with both `packetSize` on [AJP connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/ajp.html) and `ProxyIOBufferSize` in Apache2 configuration.

In Tomcat `server.xml`:

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" port="8009"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   packetSize="65536"
   proxyName="yourproxy.domain.ltd" proxyPort="80"
   />
```

In Apache2 [mod_proxy_ajp configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyiobuffersize), add the statement `ProxyIOBufferSize 65536`.

Answer (score 2):

It was found that one of the internal processes was calling that port and sending http requests causing the "Invalid message.." error. So I ended up adding an additional http Connector for those internal processes

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar message today:

```
Nov 18, 2016 4:25:00 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader
SEVERE: Invalid message received with signature 65524
```

The root cause of my problem was that selinux wasn't letting apache connect to tomcat.  I'm a little confused as to how this error was a result - I'd expect that there would be no connection, period.  Best guess, i probably attempted to manually connect to that port with telnet.  Doing that certainly gives a similar message.

Regardless, perhaps this selinux reminder will be helpful to someone else who ends up here.

Answer (score 1):

> There are no requests sent to the web or tomcat server and it still throws that error. Access logs in tomcat and apache show that no request is coming in. What is causing the invalid message error?

Just some hint for other people because I forgot the same in one of my configs by accident: The mentioned `Connector` in `server.xml` is listening globally, because only `port` is specified, without any `address`. The latter is defined to listen globally by default:

> By default, this port will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

So without any additional firewall or such it might be that bad clients are simply testing for open ports using various protocols, which might or might not be `HTTP` and therefore resulting in error messages with different signatures. Without very good reasons, there shouldn't be any need to make AJP globally available, especially not in case of a proxy-setup like used by the thread starter.

```
<Connector  address="localhost" port="port" 
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" 
            acceptorThreadCount="2" 
            maxThreads="1600" 
            redirectPort="8443" />
```