# Tomcat was stopped after 3 messages: Invalid message recieved with signature 18245

Tags: crash, tomcat6, ajp

I installed Tomcat 6 in Windows Server 2008.

From the time it was installed in 2012, there have been 9 times where Tomcat services was stopped unexpectedly. All of the times happened after 3 log messages/entries, for example:

```
Jul 17, 2015 10:08:39 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader SEVERE: Invalid message recieved with signature 18245

Jul 17, 2015 10:08:44 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader SEVERE: Invalid message recieved with signature 18245

Jul 17, 2015 10:09:51 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage processHeader SEVERE: Invalid message recieved with signature 18245
```

Here is what I have in the server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

The old thread [Ajp invalid message received with signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836156/ajp-invalid-message-received-with-signature) provided some suggestions but I am not sure it is applicable for me as the old thread did not mention that Tomcat service was stopped then.

Do you know if the existence of the AJP connector in the server.xml might cause the invalid message and then Tomcat is stopped? Or the Tomcat crash issues come from another reason?

Comment: Greets, and welcome!  it's always better to make your question *actually a question.  Right now, the question does not say much about what you're trying to solve.  Feel free to read the FAQ regarding what is a well-formed question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited my question to state what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I found the soluction below in [Ajp invalid message received with signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836156/ajp-invalid-message-received-with-signature)

Default:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Custom:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Not working. Any soluction different?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your last sentence. Is that an answer or a related question?